# Bitlocker lock removable drives at logoff

Tags: bitlocker

I recently realized that after authenticating USB devices on a machine, then completely logging out, the next user that logged in was able to access them.

Is this something in the bitlocker settings that needs to be turned on?

I would hope that when I completely log out, it would also re-lock my USB devices in the event I forget to take them with me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitLocker is a system-level feature, not a user-level feature, and this apparently also applies to removable drives. @Joe's answer is accurate but not complete, as you would still need to manually run that command each time.

If you want the drives to be locked *automatically* when you log off, you should

1. Create a script (such as batch file) that executes the `manage-bde.exe -lock <x>: -fd` command for each drive letter `<x>` that you want to lock.
2. Use `gpedit.msc` (the Group Policy Editor) and go down the path **User Configuration → Windows Settings → Scripts** and assign that script as a Logoff script.

More info on setting a logoff script, with screenshots, is available [here](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-run-a-script-or-command-at-logoff-in-windows-7-8).

Comment: Thank you. I'd love to +1 this, but with not enough 'reputation' yet, I'm unable. SE states it does record my click though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/hot-to-lock-the-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-without/6ae82827-38ee-46dc-93d2-f5d2888324c2

Looks like running this command in CMD will do the trick:
 `manage-bde -lock -ForceDismount x:` where x is the drive.

You could also create a **batch file** to make this process easier.